# Creating a loop to look up changing values in a rep call

Tags: r, loops

Consider a dataframe, in which n groups of observations have frequency values for 5 variables (A-E))

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(group=c(rep("g1",5), rep("g2",5), rep("g3",5)), 
                 variable=LETTERS[1:5],
                 frequency=sample(1:10, 15, replace=T))
```

The groups (g1, g2, g3) however have varying sizes, e.g. g1=10, g2=20, g3=30. I want to introduce this as column "offset" in the dataframe, to later calculate compositional data (frequency/offset).
I can manually assign this, by writing the group sizes (10,20,30) five times (for each variable) to the new column:

```
df$offset <- c(rep(10,5), rep(20,5), rep(30,5))
df$rel <- df$frequency/df$offset*100
```

resulting in

```
  df
       group variable frequency offset      rel
    1     g1        A         2     10 20.00000
    2     g1        B         7     10 70.00000
    3     g1        C         7     10 70.00000
    4     g1        D         7     10 70.00000
    5     g1        E         9     10 90.00000
    6     g2        A         7     20 35.00000
    7     g2        B         1     20  5.00000
    8     g2        C         3     20 15.00000
    9     g2        D         7     20 35.00000
    10    g2        E         6     20 30.00000
    11    g3        A         7     30 23.33333
    12    g3        B         6     30 20.00000
    13    g3        C         3     30 10.00000
    14    g3        D        10     30 33.33333
    15    g3        E         3     30 10.00000
```

The problem is now that i many more groups (120), and i dont want to manually assign the offset for each group.
I have a vector

```
abund <- sample(1:100, 120, replace=TRUE)
```

in which the group sizes are written.
Can i use this vector to write each group size into the `rep` calls for `df$offset`?

```
df$offset <- c(rep(abund[1],5), rep(abund[2],5), rep(abund[3],5), ..., rep(abund[i], 5))
```

I assume it is some for - loop, but i cannot handle this myself.

Sorry for being unable to come up with a better name.

desired output:

```
  df
       group variable frequency offset      rel
    1     g1        A         2     abund[1] 20.00000
    2     g1        B         7     abund[1] 70.00000
    3     g1        C         7     abund[1] 70.00000
    4     g1        D         7     abund[1] 70.00000
    5     g1        E         9     abund[1] 90.00000
    6     g2        A         7     abund[2] 35.00000
    7     g2        B         1     abund[2]  5.00000
    8     g2        C         3     abund[2] 15.00000
    9     g2        D         7     abund[2] 35.00000
    10    g2        E         6     abund[2] 30.00000
    11    g3        A         7     abund[3] 23.33333
    12    g3        B         6     abund[3] 20.00000
    13    g3        C         3     abund[3] 10.00000
    14    g3        D        10     abund[3] 33.33333
    15    g3        E         3     abund[3] 10.00000
    ..    gi        A         n     abund[i] ..
    ..    gi        B         n     abund[i] ..
    ..    gi        C         n     abund[i] ..
    ..    gi        D         n     abund[i] ..
    ..    gi        E         n     abund[i] ..
```

Please note that the group names actually vary (as they represent biological taxa). Thank you.

Comment: Also please add `set.seed` to make `sample` reproducible

Comment: replace=F was changed to replace = T

Comment: Can you also add your desired result?

Comment: done, and done. Thank you.

Comment: i want to replace the rep(10,5) .... with rep(abund[1],5) ..... for every value in abund.

Comment: But `abund[1]` is not 10, so I don't get your desired output...

Comment: Can you add your **final** desired result. Including abund

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you desired output, we can do it with `dplyr` and `tidyr::nest`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(group=c(rep("g1",5), rep("g2",5), rep("g3",5)), 
                 variable=LETTERS[1:5],
                 frequency=sample(1:10, 15, replace=TRUE))

abund <- sample(1:100, 120, replace=TRUE)
#abund[1:3] is  84 29 27
df %>%
    nest(-group) %>%
    mutate(offset = abund[1:length(group)]) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    mutate(frequency = frequency/offset)
# A tibble: 15 <U+00D7> 4
    group offset variable  frequency
   <fctr>  <int>   <fctr>      <dbl>
1      g1     84        A 0.02380952
2      g1     84        B 0.08333333
3      g1     84        C 0.08333333
4      g1     84        D 0.08333333
5      g1     84        E 0.10714286
6      g2     29        A 0.24137931
7      g2     29        B 0.03448276
8      g2     29        C 0.10344828
9      g2     29        D 0.24137931
10     g2     29        E 0.20689655
11     g3     27        A 0.25925926
12     g3     27        B 0.22222222
13     g3     27        C 0.11111111
14     g3     27        D 0.37037037
15     g3     27        E 0.11111111
```

Comment: that looks promising in my real life example. thank you very much.

Comment: @FlorianGD - (I'll delete this comment, but thanks for your comment on my question yesterday- gave me the answer I needed).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
df$offset <- rep(sample(1:100, nrow(df)/5, replace=TRUE),each=5)
df$rel <- df$frequency/df$offset*100 

   group variable frequency offset       rel
1     g1        A         2     84  2.380952
2     g1        B         7     84  8.333333
3     g1        C         7     84  8.333333
4     g1        D         7     84  8.333333
5     g1        E         9     84 10.714286
6     g2        A         7     29 24.137931
7     g2        B         1     29  3.448276
8     g2        C         3     29 10.344828
9     g2        D         7     29 24.137931
10    g2        E         6     29 20.689655
11    g3        A         7     27 25.925926
12    g3        B         6     27 22.222222
13    g3        C         3     27 11.111111
14    g3        D        10     27 37.037037
15    g3        E         3     27 11.111111
```